# IntelliJ, Maven, JRebel (?), Tomcat and Continuous Integration. How To?

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, jrebel

I am new in Java and Continuous Integration. I want to setup a development environment using IntelliJ, Maven, GIT and JRebel (this was strongly recommended by a friend of mine). Tomcat Server is on AWS, not on my local Mac OS X machine. Is it possible to use GIT / JRebel and 'update' the remote project on the fly (after saving the files?). Which modules should I install on my Mac and which on Tomcat? Do I need Jenkins as well?

Comment: If you go with IntelliJ you may as well use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as it is made by the same company and the work really nice together.

Answer (score 0):

With [JRebel Remoting](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/remoting/), it is possible to push the changes to the remote applications, without having to configure any extra ports even. This is applicable if you would like to code something in the IDE, and then just push the changes to the remote application. But if you'd like to run the full test suite, then it is better to do via CI and then you will have quite different process - you will have to wait a bit longer until your changes become visible in the running app.